# A problem in Exponential Inequalities

Tags: inequality

I was given this problem:

> Find the number of negative integral values of $x $ satisfying $4^{-x+0.5}-7× 2^{-x} \lt 4$, $x \in \mathbb {R} $.

The answer is 1.

I would have loved to show my attempts and my thoughts, but I'm clueless.

Comment: Hint: that's a quadratic inequality in $y=2^{-x}\,$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $x = -n < 0; n > 0; n \in \mathbb Z$

$4^{-x+0.5}-7× 2^{-x}=$

$4^{n + 0.5} - 7*2^n = $

$4^{n}\sqrt 4 - 7*2^{n}=$

$2^{2n}*2 - 7*2^{n} = $

$2^{2n + 1} - 7*2^{n} =$

$2^{n}[2^{n+1} - 7]<4\implies$

$2^{n+1} - 7 < 4*2^{-n} = 2^{2-n} \implies$

$2^{n+1} < 7 + \frac 1{2^{n-2}}$

If $n = 1$ then $4 < 7 + 2$

If $n \ge 2$ then $2^{n+1} \ge 8$ and $\frac 1{2^{n-2}} \le 1$ so $7 + \frac 1{2^{n-2}}\le 8 \le 2^{n+1}$.

So $x= -1$ is the only negative integer for which this is true.

Answer (score 0):

Write
$$
4^{-x+0.5}=\frac{2}{2^{2x}}
$$
so your inequality is
$$
\frac{2}{2^{2x}}-\frac{7}{2^x}-4<0
$$
that's equivalent to, after setting $2^x=t$,
$$
2-7t-4t^2<0
$$
or $4t^2+7t-2>0$. The roots of the polynomial are $-2$ and $1/4$, so the inequality is satisfied for $t<-2$ or $t>1/4$. The first interval should be discarded, because $2^x>0$, so we remain with
$$
2^x>2^{-2}
$$
that is, $x>-2$.